# Running a Powershell Script to execute sp through Windows Task Scheduler passing in variables

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a PowerShell script which runs as follows:

```
$FileDirectory = "C:\Users\User1\D3R\staging\returns\"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "LONSQL01\SQLEXPRESS" -Database "ReturnsDatabase" -Query "EXEC spImportReturn @FileDirectory = '$FileDirectory'" -verbose 4> C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportD3RReturn\ImportD3rReturn.txt
```

I want to change this so that `$FileDirectory` is not hardcoded into the script when it's running on Windows Task Scheduler.

I then change the PowerShell script as follows:

```
$FileDirectory
$VerboseDirectory

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "LONSQL01\SQLEXPRESS" -Database "ReturnsDatabase" -Query "EXEC spImportReturn @FileDirectory = '$FileDirectory'" -verbose 4> '$VerboseDirectory '
```

Now I want to call this from Windows Task Scheduler, attempting to pass the values for `$FileDirectory` and `$VerboseDirectory` from the scheduler.

So my arguments for Task Scheduler as follows:

Program/Script: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Add Arguments (optional): `-Command "& 'C:\ChrisDev\PowershellScripts\MainPrograms.ps1" -FileDirectory 'C:\users\CAsaipillai\D3R\staging\returns\' -VerboseDirectory 'C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportD3RReturn\ImportD3rReturn.txt'"`

Unfortunately nothing is happening... the stored procedure is definitely not firing.

How can I pass arguments into Windows Tasks Scheduler so they can be passed down to my script?

Comment: Why are you using `-Command` _and_ `&`?  You can just pass `-File $path -Args`.  Note that single quotes mean nothing to the `cmd.exe` interpretation for the args here.

Comment: Another oddity, where is your `param()` block?

Comment: Ive only been writing powershell for the 2nd day...so im a complete newbie to this.

Comment: Ok so i tried doing this for Arguments (optional) but that didnt work 

-File 'C:\ChrisDev\PowershellScripts\MainPrograms.ps1' -Args -FileDirectory 'C:\users\User1\D3R\staging\returns\' -VerboseDirectory 'C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportD3RReturn\ImportD3rReturn.txt'"

Comment: Give me a few and I'll write your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing a few key things.  Namely, a way to accept arguments to your script.  This is done via the `param` function:

```
param(
    $FileDirectory,
    $VerboseDirectory
)
```

I would also suggest using a feature called *splatting* which allows you to define a map of parameters to their values for more readable code:

```
$sqlParams = @{
    ServerInstance = 'LONSQL01\SQLEXPRESS'
    Database       = 'ReturnsDatabase'
    Query          = "EXEC spImportReturn @FileDirectory = '$FileDirectory'"
    Verbose        = $true
}
```

And putting that together:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd @sqlParams 4> $VerboseDirectory
```

---

Now, putting that together, you need to specify the arguments to task scheduler:

Executable: `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Arguments: `-File "C:\ChrisDev\PowershellScripts\MainPrograms.ps1" -FileDirectory "C:\users\CAsaipillai\D3R\staging\returns\" -VerboseDirectory "C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportD3RReturn\ImportD3rReturn.txt"`

Comment: Thanks for that. OK i tried that and unfortunately it didnt run. 


Then I got the following error

Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot bulk load because the file "0409" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
At line:30 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd @sqlParams 4> $VerboseDirectory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Comment: I ran that in a script and set my values as follows:


$FileDirectory = "C:\users\CAsaipillai\D3R\staging\returns\" 
$VerboseDirectory = "C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportD3RReturn\ImportD3rReturn.txt"

Comment: and permissions are set for read/write in the folders